# Why skip Yikum Purkan and Mi Sheberach on a weekday Yom Tov?

Tags: yom-tov, ashkenazi, prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer

This is a question specific to Ashkenazim (Nusach Ashkenaz, Nusach Ari, and Nusach Sefard).

On Shabbat, after the Torah Reading and before Mussaf, [3 prayers, (2 Yikkum Purkans and a Mi Sheberach) are recited](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16901&pgnum=474). On Yom Tov that falls out on a weekday, we are instructed to skip those prayers.

Why skip Yikum Purkan and the Mi Sheberach for the congregation on a holiday that falls out on a weekday?

There doesn't appear to be any Shabbat specific text, so why omit it?

Comment: I cannot pretend to understand the reason offered by _Taame Haminhagim_ 349, so will not post it as an answer. Perhaps someone who does understand it will do so.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32456&st=&pgnum=285

Comment: link to Taame Haminhagim 349: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&pgnum=174

Comment: In Yekkish kehillous the MiShebayrach following Yekum Purkon is omitted on Shabbos Mevorachim. (Yekum Purkon is said as it is on every Shabbos.)

Answer (score 3):

[Rabbi Ari Henkin’s musings](http://torahmusings.com/2010/10/yekum-purkan/) quotes the Siddur Harashban 20b to say that

> Yekum Purkan is not recited on a weekday Yom Tov in order to allow for
> the already lengthy services to end that much earlier, so that people
> can get home and prepare their Yom Tov meal.[3] Indeed, it is reserved
> especially for Shabbat, as it is primarily a prayer for those who
> study the Torah, which was given on Shabbat.[4] It is also suggested
> that Yekum Purkan is recited only on Shabbat in order to recall that
> the Exilarch[5] would be present in the synagogue on Shabbat morning
> and reciting it then was considered to be a gesture of honor towards
> him.[6]
>
> [3] Siddur Harashban 20b; Rokeaich 53.
> [4] Ziv Hashabbat p.183.
> [5] See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exilarch.
> [6] Sefer Yuchsin p.121; Safra Chadeta p. 91 cited in Rite and Reason p. 252.

I do not know why the Exilarch didn’t, as implied, come to synagogue on Yom Tov.

Comment: The early Exilarchs were likley making aliyah b'regel on yontiv.

Comment: What about the Mi Sheberach?

Comment: Who is Rashban?

Comment: @DoubleAA I have asked your question of Rav Henkin. Watch this space.

Comment: @DoubleAA The front page says Sidur Raschban von Salomon Schuck, Bezirksrabbiner Karczag. See http://hebrewbooks.org/21467. Could he be the Maharam Schik? More than this I do not know.