# Is there a minhag NOT to say "Mi Sheberach" for the ill on a weekday Yom Tov?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, yom-tov, choleh-sick

My shul has some "strange" *minhagim* that I haven't seen elsewhere. They reserve reciting the prayer for the ill for Shabbat and "regular" weekdays but will specifically **not** recite it if a Yom Tov occurs on a weekday. When I asked the rabbi why they have this minhag, he said he didn't know but this is a shul minhag dating back many years, and he has no idea why.

This could be a unique minhag to our shul. But, I'm curious if any group of people , nusach or otherwise does likewise or if there may be a source for this minhag. Obviously, I'm not including those places that have a minhag not to say this prayer in the shul ever or if they only reserve it for regular weekdays. I'm curious as to why there might be a difference between saying it on Shabbat but specifically **not** on Yom Tov.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88884/759 though seemingly a weekday is not stricter since some opinions are more lenient with ordinary requests on Yom Tov though that too is pretty controversial

Comment: @DoubleAA Very interesting source in that linked question. Thanks. It will make for an interesting future *shiur* in my shul. *Shanah Tovah* to you and family.

Comment: I speculate someone decided holidays are too celebratory to do this somber thing, while on Shabbat it's expected.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29300/9682. Before some trigger-happy close voter jumps on this, note that it’s a different Mi Shebeirach; however, it’s possible that the reasons there (allow people to go home earlier for their Seudos, etc.) could apply to this as well.