# Why is "Av haRachamim" said every Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer

With few exceptions (days when Tachanun isn't said, possibly on the *[Four Parshiyot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26763/why-omit-av-harachamim-for-the-four-parashiyos)*), the prayer *Av haRachamim,* which talks about ["the destruction of the Ashkenazi communities around the Rhine River by Christian crusaders during the First Crusade"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Av_HaRachamim), is recited on every Shabbat.  This prayer does not fit with the joyous theme of Shabbat, and as mentioned in [Why are some bakashot made on Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18510/why-are-some-bakashot-made-on-shabbat) , "prayers of request (*bakashot*)" are generally prohibited.  Why, then, is this prayer recited every week?

<sup>(I could understand if it was recited specifically during the dates when the destruction took place, but *every* week?)</sup>

Comment: Do you want a reason (why do we say it every _Shabas_) or an excuse (how dare we say it every _Shabas_) or either/both?

Comment: @msh210 What's the difference?

Comment: A reason to say it every _Shabas_ might be that the tragedy was so severe that we feel a need to mention it often or that there are more people in the synagogue on _Shabas_ than other days, for example. Those don't excuse saying a somber prayer on _Shabas_, but they are reasons to do so. An excuse for saying it every _Shabas_ might be that it doesn't count as mourning or that doesn't count as a request, for example. Those aren't reasons to say it, but they excuse saying it.

Comment: That quote from Wikipedia is taken out of context. In its proper context, it indicates _when_ the prayer was enacted, not _what_ it speaks about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Rödelheim siddur, Rallis Wiesenthal's [Siddur Sefas Yisroel](http://www.opensiddur.org/contributions/siddur-bnei-ashkenaz-a-german-rite-siddur-prepared-by-r-rallis-wiesenthal/), and the original Commonwealth edition of the Sacks Siddur, the instructions are to say Av Harachamim only on the shabbat before Shavuout and Shabbat Chazon. The custom of saying it every shabbat is, according to the former two, an innovation of Minhag Polin, which might mean that due to the even-worse conditions in Poland, it was necessary to introduce an added note of solemnity for shabbat.

Comment: A reasonable conjecture. [*Tach v'Tat*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmelnytsky_Uprising#Jews), which heavily affected Polish Jews, is linked with the [Rhineland massacres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhineland_massacres) of 1096 in [one *nusach* of א-ל מלא רחמים](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42621&st=&pgnum=520) even though the original prayer predates *Tach v'Tat*. Perhaps *Tach v'Tat* likewise compounded the importance of *Av HaRamchamim* for Polish Jews.

Comment: Polin don't say Av HaRachamim every Shabbos. They don't say it on Shabbos Mevorchim HaChodesh (except during Sefiras Haomer, i.e. Mevorchim HaChodesh Iyyar and Sivan). Polin also don't say it when צדקתך wont be said at Mincha. As I said, it is said every Shabbos (except during Pesach) of the Sefira, even in Nisan.

Comment: Prague have the same minhag as Polin, however, they also say Av HaRachamim on Shabbos Mevorchim HaChodesh Av.

Comment: @JoshuaPearl, when I say every shabbat, I mean they don't just say it those two specific shabbatot mentioned in my answer. I grew up in Eastern European-influenced schuls, so I am well aware of the exceptions you mentioned, however as above, the rule is that unless one of those exceptions occurred, Av Harachamim would be said.